# AssertionError using the spread operator

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword, spread

Trying to write a function using the spread operator to add an element to an array. Below is the code I wrote which keeps returning AssertionError: expected [ Array(5) ] to deeply equal [ 'foo', 1 ]

```
var chocolateBars = ["snickers", "hundred grand", "kitkat", "skittles"];

function addElementToBeginningOfArray(candyBars,twix) {
  return ["twix", ...chocolateBars];
}
```

Comment: Umm did you mean `[twix, ...chocolateBars];`?

Comment: for above snippet there is no error present

Comment: @Ele or maybe even `[twix, ...candyBars]`? The parameter doesn't get used otherwise.

Comment: I'm sorry if the question was not clear, it was my first time posting. But I see the error and typo now. Thank you.

Comment: Good job, @PriyaPatel ! Feel free to post an answer to your question (you can do that), or add to the body of your question with your solution. It's a good habit to help future searchers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a typo in your code? I assume you mean to do this instead:

```
var chocolateBars = ["snickers", "hundred grand", "kitkat", "skittles"];

function addElementToBeginningOfArray(candyBars,twix) {
  return ["twix", ...candyBars];
}

console.log(addElementToBeginningOfArray(chocolateBars);
```

edit: it print out: 
(5) ["twix", "snickers", "hundred grand", "kitkat", "skittles"]

Is that what you expect to see?

edit:
made the same typo as the one who ask question. corrected this line:
`return ["twix", ...candyBars];`

And indeed because being pick on typo with down voting my answer, let me elaborate more on this and being helpful. The code indeed won't throw error as the topic owner see because the variable chocolateBars has global scope. it will work. The error is more or less seem to me he/she is running a unit test but somehow expecting only one element in the array but indeed they have five? which is how that code work. it should have 5 elements in chocolateBars. so may be fixing the typo can fix his/her issue as he accidentally change chocolateBars

Comment: What's the typo?

Comment: The code in your answer and that in the question are exactly the same. I do not see how this would make a difference.

Comment: It should also probably be `twix` not `"twix"`, so it uses the parameter, instead of a hardcoded string.

Comment: I will remove the quotes. I seem to always run into trouble using quotes. Thank you for the feedback.